# Trying to make my portal accessible

Tags: css, html, accessibility

I'm trying to make my portal according to accessibility guidelines and thereby facing a problem in getting this error-

> "Header nesting - header following h1 is incorrect.
>
> Repair: Modify the header levels so only an `h1` or `h2` follows `h1`. "

this error is coming on the line------------

```
<h1> my portal</h1>
```

While there is no `h2` heading in the page's code.
Can anyone help me out in getting out with this problem.

Comment: could you please post the html markup?

Comment: @Sushy: You should add a minimal example of the HTML producing this error to your question (simply [edit] it). - And please document where this message is coming from.